# Django: Make user email required

Tags: python, django

For my application the email field of a User should be required. That's not the case for the default User model. So I thought it would make sense to create a custom user model as described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project):

> If you’re starting a new project, it’s highly recommended to set up a
>   custom user model, even if the default User model is sufficient for
>   you. This model behaves identically to the default user model, but
>   you’ll be able to customize it in the future if the need arises:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=False)
```

However, I am not sure if that's the correct way to achieve this.

The reason is that [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) the Django docs say:

> Abstract base classes are useful when you want to put some common
>   information into a number of other models. You write your base class
>   and put abstract=True in the Meta class. This model will then not be
>   used to create any database table. Instead, when it is used as a base
>   class for other models, its fields will be added to those of the child
>   class. **It is an error to have fields in the abstract base class with
>   the same name as those in the child (and Django will raise an
>   exception).**

What should I do now?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have to answer my question because now I know the solution:

The way I described in the start post should work. The docs are just wrong:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29192

Comment: You should accept your own answer, as this is the correct one. I was assuming that Django's documentation was correct. In previous versions of Django you could not override ModelFields attributes.

Answer (score 10):

add in models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

User._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True
User._meta.get_field('email').blank = False
User._meta.get_field('email').null = False
```

Comment: This change needs a migration and the migration will be created in the virtual env directory which is not included in the git repository.

Do you know any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: You have to subclass AbstractBaseUser and implement all other attributes too.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, UserManager

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=False)       
    objects = UserManager()
```

Second edit:

**Aliquis answer is the correct one**. Current documentation is simply [wrong](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes): "It is an error to have fields in the abstract base class with the same name as those in the child (and Django will raise an exception)."

Comment: Looks like this is not a solution either. 

> REQUIRED_FIELDS has no effect in other parts of Django, like creating a user in the admin.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.REQUIRED_FIELDS

Comment: I have reread your question. That's the way it to do it. But you have to take of the rest too. Have a look at the AbstractUser implementation.